# Is there a way to find a Vine URL wiht just the video address

Tags: video, video-streaming, media-player, vine

If I have a video address:

3AD7A955D51006719717420974080_1a677455f1a.4.11917992869861870006_VkhcORfQGkwOHx5_0gRUrohUXbRvkqC.XimbDJDUvbKN0CFypywZH_bBbJJ7BpiB.mp4?versionId=qNVngRHQ4Vf210uZIT5zyj_9FrWGE5Ko

Is there a script or process to find the native Vine URL: https://vine.co/v/hDq2L9PeVTX

Much appreciate, I cant seem to figure out anything.

Comment: The source isn't even obscured, it's right in the `<video>` element.

Comment: How do you figure?  I dont see the source (Vine URL) in the source video.

Comment: `<video ...><source src="{your source}">`

Comment: Ahh, I meant doing it the reverse way.  I have the source video, but I am trying to back into the Vine URL

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense.

Comment: Any suggestions to help me phrase it more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

#### don't trust Google, try [Million Short](https://millionshort.com), but remove the `versionID` part from the `MP4` video before:

```
3AD7A955D51006719717420974080_1a677455f1a.4.11917992869861870006_VkhcORfQGkwOHx5_0gRUrohUXbRvkqC.XimbDJDUvbKN0CFypywZH_bBbJJ7BpiB.mp4
```

---

[image: https://millionshort.com/search.php?q=3AD7A955D51006719717420974080_1a677455f1a.4.11917992869861870006_VkhcORfQGkwOHx5_0gRUrohUXbRvkqC.XimbDJDUvbKN0CFypywZH_bBbJJ7BpiB.mp4&remove=0]

[*search*](https://millionshort.com/search.php?q=3AD7A955D51006719717420974080_1a677455f1a.4.11917992869861870006_VkhcORfQGkwOHx5_0gRUrohUXbRvkqC.XimbDJDUvbKN0CFypywZH_bBbJJ7BpiB.mp4&remove=0)

Comment: Im getting an error message from this search, if this works I will be extremely grateful.